# Do you plan to develop Night Mode?

Tags: desktop, nightlight

Do you plan to develop any blulight filter a.k.a. "Night mode"?

Comment: It's easier to reach the developers either through [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/elementary) (where the actual development happens) or via the [subreddit](https://reddit.com/r/elementaryos), StackExchange is really meant to be for Q&A style support.

Comment: Thank for warning. I'll be more careful next time

Comment: Not a warning, just a tip so that you can find an answer quicker :)

Comment: I'd love to have this feature too !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to look at the package `redshift` (`universe` packages) or fluxgui (in the PPA: https://launchpad.net/~nathan-renniewaldock/+archive/ubuntu/flux)

Comment: If you use Redshift then I can recommend also installing this elementary-style indicator icon for redshift-gtk - the original one looks very out of place. https://gist.github.com/tobias-kuendig/d055892720cf09ae1a9d82075fb0f408

Comment: I just installed `Redshift` in AppCenter which I think is already elementary-style and pretty good for me.

Answer (score 3):

`f.lux` is more reliable than `Redshift` and has a wing panel icon to easily adjust the color and pause it.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nathan-renniewaldock/flux
sudo apt update
sudo apt install fluxgui
```

Answer (score 2):

This will be in elementary OS Juno 5.0 without the need for any thirdparty software.

See

- https://medium.com/elementaryos/juno-progress-for-january-february-9b276042716e#770b and
- https://github.com/elementary/wingpanel-indicator-nightlight

Answer (score 1):

f.lux apparently currently does not support monitors with high colour depth. Redshift does. Redshift also seems more happy with dealing with multiple different multiple monitor set ups. As a result I have had to move from f.lux to Redshift after quite a few years happy usage for I hope they continue to develop it.